# json encoding 2 dimension array

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have the following in php:

```
$query = mysql_query($sql);
$rows = mysql_num_rows($query); 
$data['course_num']=$rows;
$data['course_data'] = array();
while ($fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($query) )
{

    $courseData = array(
    'course_name'=>$fetch['course_name'],
    'training_field'=>$fetch['training_field'],
    'speciality_field'=>$fetch['speciality_field'],
    'language'=>$fetch['language'],
    'description'=>$fetch['description'],
    'type'=>$fetch['type'],
    );

    array_push($data['course_data'],$courseData);
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

when I receive the result of this script in jquery (using post)

I log it using :

```
console.log(data['course_data']);
```

and the output is :

```
[Object { course_name="Introduction to C++",  training_field="Engineering" ,  speciality_field="Software",  more...}]
```

But I can't seem to figure out how to access the elements.

I tried

```
data['course_data'].course_name

data['course_data']['course_name']
```

Nothing worked. Any ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `array_push($data['course_data'],$courseData);` you are actually putting `$courseData` at `$data['course_data'][0]` and therefore you would access it in JavaScript as `data['course_data'][0]['course_name']`.

If you only intend to have one result, instead of `array_push($data['course_data'],$courseData);` you should just specify `$data['course_data'] = $courseData`. Otherwise, you should iterate over `data['course_data']` like so:

```
for (i in data['course_data']) {
  console.log(data['course_data'][i]['course_name']);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should specify the index in the first array for instance

```
data['course_data'][0]['course_name'];
```

you could make it better if you had defined the first array just as variable not a variable within an array

Answer (score 0):

```
$data['course_data'][0]['course_name']
```

should do the trick. If not please send the output of var_dump($data)

Comment: I think this is a JS problem, not a PHP

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the PHP code is correct, you will receive a JSON data like:

```
{
    "course_num":34,
    "course_data":[
        {
            "course_name":"name_value",
            ....
        },
        ....etc (other object based on SQL result)
    ]
}
```

So, if you want to access to the total number of result:

```
data.course_num
```

If you want to access to the first element of the list of result:

```
data.course_data[0]
```

If you want to access to the name of the first element of the list of result:

```
data.course_data[0].course_name
```

or

```
data.course_data[0]['course_name']
```

Answer (score 0):

use jquery's parseJSON method to get all the goodies out of the json object...

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/